# Signal in one channel, noise on both – tool to exploit this for noise reduction

Tags: microphone, stereo, noise-reduction

I have a stereo microphone recording that features two sources:

- The *signal* is considerably more prominent in the left channel than in the right one.
- The *noise* is present in both channels but slightly more so in the right one. It’s a combination of different types of undesired sounds including machine sounds, human activity and traffic noise (through a wall). It drastically changes over time.

Here is an close-up of the signals of a section featuring only the noise (logarithmic amplitude scale):

[image: Example]

Now, I want to filter out the signal as well as possible exploiting the aforementioned special properties of my recording (as opposed to standard noise reduction).
I already tried to simply subtract the right channel from the left one¹.
The result was surprisingly good, but I suspect that I can do even better with a more sophisticated tool.

Is there any tool dedicated to this?
Or is there a combination of standard tools that I am missing?

I am currently working with Audacity; thus I prefer a solution using it when in doubt.

---

¹ I later found [this blog post](https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/removing-background-noise-in-audacity-by-differencing-stereo-channels), which does something similar plus regular noise reduction.

Comment: The phase-invert trick only works on non-random sources. 'noise' may or may not be random, depending on its source.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Well, it’s not random (in the sense that it independently acts on each channel) as you can see in the image.

Comment: The waves may be somewhat similar, but they are not phase invertable to zero.

Comment: … which is why I want something sophisticated than a plain subtraction (phase inversion + mix).

Comment: …which is what I offered in my answer...

Comment: Showing a waveform is not very useful in instances like this. Do you have a frequency plot instead? That will be much better at showing us what the noise actually is

Comment: @RoryAlsop: The characteristics of the noise (and thus the frequency spectrum) drastically change over time and thus I doubt that it is of much use. I don’t show the waveform is not to characterise the noise but to highlight how similarly the noise affects the two channels.

Comment: RX is amazing at removing machinery, hiss, hum, ambient noises etc. I don't bother with Audacity any more as it is too complicated - just try running your audio through RX and let it do it's thing - it may fix the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

These days this is a simple task, using specialist software like [Izotope RX](https://www.izotope.com/en/products/rx.html). However, simple is not cheap;)

Audacity has something along those lines, but I've no idea how good it is - https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/noise_reduction.html

Comment: That feature of Audacity is just standard noise reduction using a signal-free passage to estimate the spectrum of noise to remove it. It does not exploit the fact that the signal is dominant in one channel only.

Comment: Yeah - that's what you get for 'free' I'm afraid. Try the trial of RX. Stuff like that is pretty much a 1-click fix.

Comment: Can you name a specific feature that does what I want? Right now, I have to rely on your confidence and that I managed to communicate my intentions to you. Also a name may help to find similar features in other software.

Comment: It depends on what the noise is. De-hum, de-rustle, de-wind, de-crackle, dialog isolate, spectral de-noise… RX also has a 1-button 'fix it for me' mode.

Comment: The noise is what is recorded on the second channel. That’s the main point of my question.

Comment: You have yet to offer any description of the noise - in return all I can offer are the names of various types of noise reduction. We're now just going round in ever-decreasing circles.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question or the special properties of my recording. All those names do not suggest that the tools exploit that you have a separate recording of the noise (or similar). It may be that they have a specific option that uses this, but then it would be that option (and its name) that I am after. For example, in [this description and picture of RX’s spectral denoise tool](https://www.izotope.com/en/products/rx/features/spectral-de-noise.html), I see no indication that it lets me mark one channel as a noise recording.

Comment: It would have just been quicker to try the demo. It doesn't need a 'sample' it can figure it out itself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are talking about the *same* noise rather than the same *kind* of noise on both channels, the problem you have here is essentially echo compensation with a comparatively short filter length (hopefully).  The common algorithm for that task is called "LMS algorithm".  For whatever reason, I've not found implementations in the usual load of free filter plugins but maybe I just have problems looking well.